# Angular form validation failed, caused some problems?

Tags: angular, forms, angular2-form-validation

I have this form or formarray and book model:

```
class Book {
  id: number;
  active: boolean;
  name: string;
}
```

```
bookForm: FormGroup;

results: Book[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.results = [
    {id: 1, active: true, name: aaa},
    {id: 2, active: true, name: bbb},
    {id: 3, active: true, name: ccc},
  ];

  this.bookForm = this.fb.group({
    bookArray: this.fb.array(results.map(res => this.fb.group({
      id: [res.id],
      active: [res.active],
      name: [res.name, {
        validators: [BookValidators.required(`name`)],
        asyncValidators: [BookValidators.unique(`name`, (value: string) => {
              return this.service.checkNameUnique(value, res.id);
        })],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      }]
    })))
  });
}
```

So I initiate formArray with the existing results and show this formArray tables

```
id   active   name
1     true    aaa
2     true    bbb
3     true    ccc
```

in this table, the name column is editable. When I edit `'aaa'` to `'bbb'`, the form validation will fail obviously, cause it has unique validation with `updateOn: 'blur'`. question is: if I keep this change: `'aaa' -> 'bbb'`. then click other name fields, other name fields cannot be edited. This seems reasonable, But I just don't need it.

Comment: Please post the individual questions separately.

Comment: Are you ask about `form.get('bookArray').at(index).get('name').invalid` or about `form.invalid`? NOTE: It's only a way to refered to the element, depending your .html you can simplyed the "invalid of the name"

Comment: if a form is invalid after validation. How to change the form status to valid and return the form value to original?

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the change `aaa -> bbb`, other fields are disabled. Angular doesn't do that itself, you must have some code to disable the other fields. Post some HTML to give us more info.

For getting the custom errors, you need to put validators. See [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators)

Comment: No, I mean if keeping the change, other fields cannot be edited, but I need to edit other field. The truth is: if form validation failed, other fields cannot be edited. This is what I don't want.

Comment: Why can't they be edited ? That's what we need to know. The fields should still be editable, unless you have put some code to disable the inputs

Comment: I thik the reason is the form validation failed, until the validation success, you cannot  edit other field. But I'm not sure

Comment: Can you post the template also and create a reproduction on stackblitz if possible.